# Random generator does not work it always shows 0

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PouAbilites {
    protected int Health;

    public int getHealth(){
        return this.Health;
    }

    public void setHealth(final int Health){
        final Random random  = new Random();

        final int randomInt = random.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.Health=randomInt;  
    }
    PouAbilites(){
       this.Eletero=getEletero();
    }
    public void onscreen(){
        System.out.println("Health: "+ this.Health);
    }
}
```

The `main` function is included in an other class:

```
package KotelezoProgram;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final PouAbilites Pou = new PouAbilites();
        Pou.onscreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setHealth()`

Comment: PouAbilites(){ this.Eletero=getEletero(); }

Comment: [hehehe](https://www.xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: what is this.Eletero ? It's not defined in the class.

Answer (score 0):

call `setHealth()` in between

```
PouAbilites Pou = new PouAbilites();
Pou.onscreen();
```

calls

Calling `onscreen()` before `setHealth()` will return `0` because `this.Health` is just initialized in the `Pou` object to zero.